# Return the same word repeated twice, followed by the length of the new doubled word

Tags: python

I want to define a function

```
def double_word(word)
    return
```

where

```
print(double_word('Hello'))  # should be 'HelloHello10'
print(double_word('abc'))    # should be 'abcabc6'
```

Answer (score 5):

```
def double_word(word):
    return word + word + str(len(word) * 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def double_word(word):
    result=word*2
    return result + str(len(result))


print(double_word("hello"))  # Should return hellohello10
print(double_word("abc"))  # Should return abcabc6
print(double_word(""))  # Should return 0
```

Output:
hellohello10
abcabc6
0

Answer (score 1):

```py
def double_word(word):
    word = word * 2
    return word + str(len(word))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thank you for providing an answer. This could potentially be a great answer if you add some additional explanation/information. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

```
def double_word(word):
    return word * 2 + str(len(word * 2))

print(double_word("hello")) # Should return hellohello10
print(double_word("abc"))   # Should return abcabc6
print(double_word(""))      # Should return 0
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: It's inefficient to double the string twice when you can just double the length.

Answer (score 0):

```
def double_word(word):
    return word + word +str(2*len(word))
print(double_word("hello")) # Should return hellohello10
print(double_word("abc"))   # Should return abcabc6
print(double_word(""))      # Should return 0
Here is your output:
hellohello10
abcabc6
0
```

Comment: You just reposted https://stackoverflow.com/a/59979035

Answer (score 0):

all the above codes lead to pass the question, in my opinion to understand what u are doing to play around strings so I prefer to assign variable for how many time it ask me to repeat the word,

```py
total_repeat = 2
```

and another variable for the length of word

```py
total_len = word
```

and now call back them all together

```py
return word * total_repeat + str(len(total_len*total_repeat))
```

and final code will be

```py
def double_word(word):
  total_repeat = 2
  total_len = word
     return word*total_repeat + str(len(total_len*total_repeat))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   def double_word(word):
    return str(word*2)+str(len(word*2))

print(double_word("hello")) # Should return hellohello10
print(double_word("abc"))   # Should return abcabc6
print(double_word(""))      # Should return 0
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def double_word(word):

 word=word*2

 return str(word)+str(len(word))
```

Comment: Consider adding an explanation to your code in the future!

Comment: You just reposted https://stackoverflow.com/a/60412963 and you don't need to convert a string to a string.

Answer (score -1):

```
def double_word(word):
    return (word * 2) + str(len(word*2))

print(double_word("hello")) # Should return hellohello10
```

Comment: You just reposted https://stackoverflow.com/a/60823737

Answer (score -1):

```
def double_word(word):

      word = word *2

      return word + srt(len(word))
```

Comment: You just reposted https://stackoverflow.com/a/61532906 but with a typo